# Position absolute stops select drop down from opening

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my site I have a table which displays nutritional information of products. The table is too big when in mobile view so I've altered it so that in mobile view only one column is shown and this can be changed by selecting an option in the select drop down.

This is the html (I've shortened this as I don't think the whole page is necessary):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="js/products.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/products.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/productsMobile.css">


</head>

<body onload='showSize()' onresize='sizeDisplay()'>

<div class="tab">

<h2 align="center">Butteries</h2>
<p>Our butteries are all handmade using a traditional recipe that dates back to the early 1900's and has been slightly improved to our modern ways.
The taste of this traditional North-East breakfast snack was a mainstay on fishermen's trawlers for decades and is adored by local people to accompany their morning cup of tea or coffee. </p>

<p><b>Click on the tab of the buttery you want to find out more of</b></p>

<div class="wrapper" align="center">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openProduct(event, 'Standard')">Standard</button>

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openProduct(event, 'Premnay')">Premnay</button>

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openProduct(event, 'Veggie')">Veggie</button>

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openProduct(event, 'Banffshire')">Banffshire</button>
</div>

</div>


<div id ='sizes'>
    <p>Select size you want to know more about</p>
    <select id="sizeOption" required name="sizeOption" class="sizeOption" onchange="showSize()" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="per-pack" selected="selected">Per Pack</option>
    <option value="per-100g" >Per 100g</option>
    <option value="single" >Per Buttery</option>
    </select>
    
    </div>

<div id="Standard" class="tabcontent" align="center">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<img src="pageUploads/butteries stacked.jpeg" id="tableImage" align="left" height="300px">


  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

    <tr>

    <th></th>

    <th class='per-pack'>Per 4 Pack(200G)</th>

    <th class='per-100g'>Per 100g</th>

    <th class='single'>Per Buttery(50G)</th>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <th>Calories</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>724</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>362</td>

      <td class='single'>181</td>

     </tr>

     <tr class="even">

      <th>Fat</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>43.1g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>21.6g</td>

      <td class='single'>10.8g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr>

      <th>Saturated</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>15.7g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>7.9g</td>

      <td class='single'>3.9g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr class="even">

      <th>Sodium</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>1,941.9mg</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>971mg</td>

      <td class='single'>485.5mg</td>

     </tr>

    <tr>

      <th>Carbohydrates</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>78.6g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>39.3g</td>

      <td class='single'>19.7g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr class="even">

      <th>Fiber</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>0g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>0g</td>

      <td class='single'>0g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr>

      <th>Sugar</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>10.9g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>5.5g</td>

      <td class='single'>2.7g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr class="even">

      <th>Protein</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>10.5g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>5.3g</td>

      <td class='single'>2.6g</td>

     </tr>


</table>


</div>



<script>

document.getElementById('sizes').style.display = 'none';

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
function openProduct(evt, product) {


  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";

  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {

    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");

  }

  document.getElementById(product).style.display = "block";
  
let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;

    if (isMobile) {
         document.getElementById('sizes').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sizes').style.display = 'none';
    }


  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}

function showSize() {

let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;
   let per_pack = document.getElementsByClassName('per-pack');
   let per_100g = document.getElementsByClassName('per-100g');
   let single = document.getElementsByClassName('single');
   
   let size = document.getElementById("sizeOption").value;

  if(isMobile) {
 
    if (size === 'per-pack') {

    for (i = 0; i < per_pack.length; i++) {
    per_pack[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < per_100g.length; i++) {
    per_100g[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
    for (i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    single[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
    } else if (size === 'per-100g') {
    
    for (i = 0; i < per_pack.length; i++) {
    per_pack[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < per_100g.length; i++) {
    per_100g[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
    for (i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    single[i].style.display = "none";
  }
    } else if(size === 'single') {
    
    for (i = 0; i < per_pack.length; i++) {
    per_pack[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < per_100g.length; i++) {
    per_100g[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
    for (i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    single[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
    }
    
  } else {
  
      for (i = 0; i < per_pack.length; i++) {
    per_pack[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < per_100g.length; i++) {
    per_100g[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
    for (i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    single[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
  }
    
}

function sizeDisplay() {
let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;

    if (!isMobile) {
        document.getElementById('sizes').style.display = 'none';
        
    } else {
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {

        if (tabcontent[i].style.display !== '' || undefined) {
            document.getElementById('sizes').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

  }
  
     showSize();

}
```

CSS:

```
body {font-family: Arial;}



/* Style the tab */

.tab {

  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e0e0d1;

}


.tab p {
text-align: center;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {

  background-color: inherit;

  float: center;

  border: none;

  outline: none;

  cursor: pointer;

  padding: 14px 16px;

  transition: 0.3s;

  font-size: 17px;
    

}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.button {

}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {

  background-color: #ddd;

}



/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {

  background-color: #ccc;

}



/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {

  display: none;

  padding: 6px 12px;

  border: 1px solid #ccc;

  border-top: none;

}



table {

width: 600px;

}



th, td {

padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;

}



th {

text-transform: uppercase;

letter-spacing: 0.1em;

font-size:90%;

bottom-border: 2px solid #111111;

border-top:1px solid #999;

text-align: left;

}


tr.even{

background-color: #efefef; 

}



tr:hover {

background-color: #c3e6e5;

}

  @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
      
html,body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


table {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 400px;
}


#sizes p {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#sizes {
    margin-top: 300px;
    z-index:-1;
    position: absolute;
}

#sizes select {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  outline: none;
}


#sizes select option {
  padding: 20px;
}



}
```

The issue I'm having is that the select drop down no longer opens and it appears to be caused by:

```
#sizes {
    margin-top: 300px;
    z-index:-1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

When I remove the position: absolute, the drop down can open again, however, I am needing this as I am wanting to be able to move the drop down below the image. The alternative would be to basically duplicate the drop down for each tab in the page but I thought just having it once and then using css to move it down would be neater.

So how can I get around this? Why does position:absolute stop it from opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem comes not from `position: absolute;` but from `z-index:-1;`. So you are basically telling it to be hidden, as initial value for z-index it 0, but your block has -1.

P.S. I had to modify your initial code a little so that the select would always be visible for demonstration purposes

```js
function openProduct(evt, product) {


  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";

  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {

    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");

  }

  document.getElementById(product).style.display = "block";
  
let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;

    if (isMobile) {
         document.getElementById('sizes').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sizes').style.display = 'none';
    }


  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}

function showSize() {

let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;
   let per_pack = document.getElementsByClassName('per-pack');
   let per_100g = document.getElementsByClassName('per-100g');
   let single = document.getElementsByClassName('single');
   
   let size = document.getElementById("sizeOption").value;

  if(isMobile) {
 
    if (size === 'per-pack') {

    for (i = 0; i < per_pack.length; i++) {
    per_pack[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < per_100g.length; i++) {
    per_100g[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
    for (i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    single[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
    } else if (size === 'per-100g') {
    
    for (i = 0; i < per_pack.length; i++) {
    per_pack[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < per_100g.length; i++) {
    per_100g[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
    for (i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    single[i].style.display = "none";
  }
    } else if(size === 'single') {
    
    for (i = 0; i < per_pack.length; i++) {
    per_pack[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < per_100g.length; i++) {
    per_100g[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
    for (i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    single[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
    }
    
  } else {
  
      for (i = 0; i < per_pack.length; i++) {
    per_pack[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < per_100g.length; i++) {
    per_100g[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
    for (i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
    single[i].style.display = "table-cell";
  }
  
  }
    
}

function sizeDisplay() {
let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;

    if (!isMobile) {
        document.getElementById('sizes').style.display = 'none';
        
    } else {
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {

        if (tabcontent[i].style.display !== '' || undefined) {
            document.getElementById('sizes').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

  }
  
     showSize();

}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}



/* Style the tab */

.tab {

  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e0e0d1;

}


.tab p {
text-align: center;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {

  background-color: inherit;

  float: center;

  border: none;

  outline: none;

  cursor: pointer;

  padding: 14px 16px;

  transition: 0.3s;

  font-size: 17px;
    

}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.button {

}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {

  background-color: #ddd;

}



/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {

  background-color: #ccc;

}



/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {

  display: none;

  padding: 6px 12px;

  border: 1px solid #ccc;

  border-top: none;

}



table {

width: 600px;

}



th, td {

padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;

}



th {

text-transform: uppercase;

letter-spacing: 0.1em;

font-size:90%;

bottom-border: 2px solid #111111;

border-top:1px solid #999;

text-align: left;

}


tr.even{

background-color: #efefef; 

}



tr:hover {

background-color: #c3e6e5;

}


      
html,body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


table {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 400px;
}


#sizes p {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#sizes {
    margin-top: 300px;
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
}

#sizes select {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  outline: none;
}


#sizes select option {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="js/products.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/products.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/productsMobile.css">


</head>

<body onload='showSize()' onresize='sizeDisplay()'>

<div class="tab">

<h2 align="center">Butteries</h2>
<p>Our butteries are all handmade using a traditional recipe that dates back to the early 1900's and has been slightly improved to our modern ways.
The taste of this traditional North-East breakfast snack was a mainstay on fishermen's trawlers for decades and is adored by local people to accompany their morning cup of tea or coffee. </p>

<p><b>Click on the tab of the buttery you want to find out more of</b></p>

<div class="wrapper" align="center">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openProduct(event, 'Standard')">Standard</button>

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openProduct(event, 'Premnay')">Premnay</button>

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openProduct(event, 'Veggie')">Veggie</button>

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openProduct(event, 'Banffshire')">Banffshire</button>
</div>

</div>


<div id ='sizes'>
    <p>Select size you want to know more about</p>
    <select id="sizeOption" required name="sizeOption" class="sizeOption" onchange="showSize()" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="per-pack" selected="selected">Per Pack</option>
    <option value="per-100g" >Per 100g</option>
    <option value="single" >Per Buttery</option>
    </select>
    
    </div>

<div id="Standard" class="tabcontent" align="center">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<img src="pageUploads/butteries stacked.jpeg" id="tableImage" align="left" height="300px">


  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

    <tr>

    <th></th>

    <th class='per-pack'>Per 4 Pack(200G)</th>

    <th class='per-100g'>Per 100g</th>

    <th class='single'>Per Buttery(50G)</th>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <th>Calories</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>724</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>362</td>

      <td class='single'>181</td>

     </tr>

     <tr class="even">

      <th>Fat</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>43.1g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>21.6g</td>

      <td class='single'>10.8g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr>

      <th>Saturated</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>15.7g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>7.9g</td>

      <td class='single'>3.9g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr class="even">

      <th>Sodium</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>1,941.9mg</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>971mg</td>

      <td class='single'>485.5mg</td>

     </tr>

    <tr>

      <th>Carbohydrates</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>78.6g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>39.3g</td>

      <td class='single'>19.7g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr class="even">

      <th>Fiber</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>0g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>0g</td>

      <td class='single'>0g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr>

      <th>Sugar</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>10.9g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>5.5g</td>

      <td class='single'>2.7g</td>

     </tr>

    <tr class="even">

      <th>Protein</th>

      <td class='per-pack'>10.5g</td>

      <td class='per-100g'>5.3g</td>

      <td class='single'>2.6g</td>

     </tr>


</table>


</div>






</body>
```

Comment: Apologies for delay in response, been a busy day. But thank you! Thought I had been doing the z-index correctly. That's it now working